# Tiling in Ubuntu Unity 22.10?

Tags: unity, kde, tiling

How can I switch on tiling in Ubuntu Unity 22.10? Offer please some apps for this. Tactile in Extension manager is not supported...kwin-bismuth was installed, but I don't understand how to use it =_=. I hope such a stuff will be added in 23.04...

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Ubuntu Unity is an official flavor starting at Ubuntu Unity 22.10; at 22.04 it was a remix and is thus off-topic*  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuUnity/22.10/Proposal

Comment: No problem, I'm ready to listen on this solution in Ubuntu Unity 22.10. After all, I'm going to install Ubuntu Unity 23.04....

Comment: Don't forget there are differences with 22.04 & 22.10.... Ubuntu Unity 22.04 LTS was a *respin* and not *flavor*, thus included 3rd party packages that had to be *dropped* when official *flavor* was reached...  Yes the [Ubuntu Unity] team worked hard to get everything included they could (*uploading to 'universe' what they could*), but 22.04 is still different due to 3rd party package inclusion.